# System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in your application(E.g. MyApplication.exe)

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle11g, windows-7-x64

I am using Windows Application to communicate with Oracle 11g database to fetch some data. Oracle database was installed on the X64 bit system.
My Application builds successfully on my system (the x86 bit) with x64 bit dlls of Oracle. But when I run application below mentioned errors occurred.

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in your application(E.g. MyApplication.exe)
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.**

I had tried different ways to resolve this issue but still unable to found a solution for same. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which different ways have you tried?

Comment: Are you building as x64? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx

Comment: I have downloaded ODAC 11 XCopy and copied Oracle.DataAccess.dll from \odp.net4\odp.net\bin\4 and used it as a reference into my application.

Comment: @mjwills - Yes I tried building an application on x64,x86, and Any CPU.

Comment: Where are you changing the configuration? You should right click on the solution, properties, and check the configuration manager.
System.BadImageFormatException is always related to building a x86 into x64 or viceversa

Comment: @Nakeniehl - Yes I have changed the configuration from configuration manager. Actually, my system is x86 and I want to add the application on x64 bit OS. So on what platform should I build my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load a 64bit DLL from a 32 bit process or vice versa. Make sure the DLLs you want to load have the same bitness as your process.

Comment: Thanks, Markus. I have loaded the same version of dll as per OS on which I am deploying my application. It works like charm.